# Filebeat failing to send logs to logstash with log/harvester error

Tags: docker, logstash, filebeat

I'm following this tutorial to get logs from my docker containers stored in elasticsearch via filebeat and logstash [Link to tutorial](https://medium.com/@sece.cosmin/docker-logs-with-elastic-stack-elk-filebeat-50e2b20a27c6)

However, nothing is being shown in kibana and when I run a docker-logs on my filebeat container, I'm getting the following error

```
2019-03-30T22:22:40.353Z        ERROR   log/harvester.go:281    Read line error: parsing CRI timestamp: parsing time "-03-30T21:59:16,113][INFO" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "-03-30T21:59:16,113][INFO" as "2006"; File: /usr/share/dockerlogs/data/2f3164397450efdd5851c3fad67fe405ab3dd822bbea1d807a993844e9143d5e/2f3164397450efdd5851c3fad67fe405ab3dd822bbea1d807a993844e9143d5e-json.log
```

My containers are hosted on a linux virtual machine where the virtual machine is running on a windows machine (Not sure if this could be causing the error due to the locations specified)

Below I'll describe what's running and some files in case the article is deleted in the future etc

One container is running which is simply running the following command, printing lines that filebeat should be able to read

```
CMD while true; do sleep 2 ; echo "{\"app\": \"dummy\", \"foo\": \"bar\"}"; done
```

My filebeat.yml file is as follows

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: docker
  combine_partial: true
  containers:
    path: "/usr/share/dockerlogs/data"
    stream: "stdout"
    ids:
      - "*"
  exclude_files: ['\.gz$']
  ignore_older: 10m

processors:
  # decode the log field (sub JSON document) if JSON encoded, then maps it's fields to elasticsearch fields
- decode_json_fields:
    fields: ["log", "message"]
    target: ""
    # overwrite existing target elasticsearch fields while decoding json fields    
    overwrite_keys: true
- add_docker_metadata:
    host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

# setup filebeat to send output to logstash
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash"]

# Write Filebeat own logs only to file to avoid catching them with itself in docker log files
logging.level: error
logging.to_files: false
logging.to_syslog: false
loggins.metrice.enabled: false
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0644
ssl.verification_mode: none
```

Any suggestions on why filebeat is failing to forward my logs and how to fix it would be appreciated. Thanks